# Javascript runtime error unrecognized expression # in jquery.min.js

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I am developing a C# / ASP.NET web application in Visual Studio 2015 and I'm using a Boostrap Nav bar for the menu. Everything was working fine until recently when the menu stopped working. I have all the JQuery script and css references in place and I've made no changes to the these file but the Nav bar will not respond. Below is the portion of the output I'm getting in VS 2015. The browser is IE Explorer 11.0.9. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

'iexplore.exe' (Script): Loaded 'Sourcemap (http://localhost:58132/js/bootstrap.min.js)'. 
'iexplore.exe' (Script): Loaded 'Sourcemap (http://localhost:58132/js/bootstrap.min.js)'
. 
Exception was thrown at line 2, column 13464 in http://localhost:58132/js/jquery.min.js
0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #

Exception was thrown at line 2, column 13464 in http://localhost:58132/js/jquery.min.js
0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #

Exception was thrown at line 2, column 13464 in http://localhost:58132/js/jquery.min.js
0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #

UPDATE:
I tried removing the JQuery files and then re-adding them, rebuilding but that didn't work. I'm getting this error for jquery-3.2.1.clim.min.js as well. I cannot locate the line and column where said syntax error is because the files dont open with lines or columns - just 4 very long lines. I have also tried mapping to the CDN  for these files and get the same result - 11 exceptions for jquery.min.js and 11 for jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js. I've posted one of each below to save space here - the error msg is the same for all 22

Exception was thrown at line 2, column 13464 in http://localhost:58132/js/jquery.min.js
0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #

Exception was thrown at line 2, column 13568 in http://localhost:58132/js/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js
0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #

UPDATE 2:  I think I've narrowed down the issue. In the Bootstrap Nav bar I have/need href="#" - when I remove the # there are no Output errors but the Nav bar still wont work.

Comment: There isn't enough info here. Show us what code gets executed at `line 2, column 13464` in jquery.min.js and what code is executed before that maybe we can help.

Comment: try removing jquery from your project and add it again, rebuild the project and it should solve the issue

Comment: Do you have any .js script of your own included via script tag or in inline scripts? If so, please provide them. The error is not really in jQuery but in the argument that is passed to a jQuery function.

Comment: @trincot - I think I've narrowed down the issue. In the Bootstrap Nav bar I have/need href="#" - when I remove the # there are no Output errors but the Nav bar still wont work. Also, there is this script in the markup:
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function ShowPopup() {
            $("#btnShowPopup").click();
        }
    </script>

Comment: Do you have any code that has `$("#" + somevariable)`, or something similar? I see no relationship between the `href="#"` and the error you get. Do you maybe have `id` attributes in your NavBar that have a space or hyphen in their value?